# append a value to form with jquery and serialize the form for AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has an input that gets filled by the user and is sent as a serialized form with an AJAX Post request. I want to append a value to my form before sending it but it seems like it is not working (I have used Chrome's debugger and I can see that the only part that is not working is the append part). Here is my code:

```
 var $form = $("#confirmPhoneNumberForm");
    var phoneNumber = $("input[name='EmailOrPhoneNumber']").val();
    $form.append("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    var formlog = $form.serialize();
    console.log(formlog);
```

In the `console.log()` part it just shows the input that the user enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending **the value** of your EmailOrPhoneNumber input to the form, instead of the input element itself.

The `.serialize()` function can only serialize the values of form elements.

Try removing `.val();` from your phoneNumber declaration.

Comment: it is still sending null to the server. but in console.log it shows EmailOrPhoneNumber input (not its value

Comment: I have just made a quick jsbin and it seems to work for me https://jsbin.com/ketazuriri/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: this is my formlog var after ythe changes "code=1234&EmailOrPhoneNumber=%DB%B0%DB%B9%DB%B1%DB%B7%DB%B5%DB%B7%DB%B3%DB%B5%DB%B6%DB%B1%DB%B4"   and code is the input that user enters